# how to bind a name value to a for loop using moment-timezone

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a list of time zones that has been populated as a query as follows:

```
async load(){
    this.usertimezones = await this.query(gets my query result)
}
```

This is what the usertimezones looks like:

```
0: {userId: '0b8502d0-0b65-4092-bc4e-5c491acc7771', timezone: 'Africa/Bamako', isActive: true, id: '69c6051b-5b8b-43cf-b771-7884b6eb5c01'}
1: {userId: '0b8502d0-0b65-4092-bc4e-5c491acc7771', timezone: 'America/Araguaina', isActive: true, id: 'b609808d-3002-422a-810c-8d3e17c972bc'}
```

For each timezone, I pass it as follows:

```
    async load(){
        this.usertimezones = await this.query(gets my query result)
        this.usertimezones.forEach(x => {
            let test = Mo().tz(x.timezone).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a');
            console.log(test);
        })
    }
```

And then the output is as follows:

```
March 15th 2022, 7:53 pm
March 15th 2022, 4:53 pm
```

However, now I can't tell which timezone each result belongs to. How do I add the timezone name to it, and push it to an array, so it looks like this?

```
Africa/Bamako March 15th 2022, 7:53 pm
America/Araguaina March 15th 2022, 4:53 pm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can re-use `x.timezone` in your `forEach` function. Like so:

```
const result = [];
this.usertimezones.forEach(x => {
    const time = Mo().tz(x.timezone).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a');
    const str = x.timezone + ' ' + test;
    console.log(str);
    result.push(str);
})
```

The above code will log out the desired output, as well as pushing it into the `result` array.